# How to create a playlist of mp3 files from storage

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded my files with the storage and i have created records for each files informations in the database. Now I want to create a playlist and add a simple html audio player for each of them. how can I do this using the Storage filesystem? Is that possible at all or must I put all files to public?

something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but you can add a Route function to pull files out of the 'storage' folders with a simple Route entry:

```
// Used to retrieve the media files
Route::get('media/{filename}', function ($filename) {
    $path = storage_path('app') . '/media/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```